# Tor on TP-Link TL-WR740N/ND to route all traffic

Tags: routers

I would like to setup a Tor router using my TP-Link TL-WR740N/ND flashed with OpenWRT. I have found https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/OpenWRT which would explain how to do what I'm looking for but I' mnot gettingvery far due to:

```
# opkg install tor
Unknown package 'tor'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package tor.
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

Why can it not install the tor package?

Comment: The TL-WR740N/ND has 32MB of main memory. I'm not sure if that's enough to run Tor or not, but this thread would suggest it's not: https://www.gargoyle-router.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7135 Others may have a better idea.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks strongly agreed! I'm running Tor node, and there's at least 512Mb total system ram needed for proper work. Based on RPi tests

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain you ran `opkg update` as a preliminary step, then it's possible that the repository isn't up to date.

One thing you could do instead is pull your own copy from the [OpenWRT GitHub repository](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/tree/master/net/tor). This includes a Makefile that pulls the latest version of Tor from the Tor site.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work! I had this router and his "older brothers" [ since my last comment ] and tried Tor on it - it lags like hell! And even a physically launching Tor on it fails sometimes : it needs a RAM space, not this tiny amount on-board. Use Raspberry Pi connected by wire and acting like wireless AP. Feel free to ask for further details.